# Embedded WMP control - how to get resolution of current playing file?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, wmp, asf

I have a Windows Media Player control embedded inside my webpage, I feed it some URL to stream from (ASF file).
How can I get from the WMP control the resolution in pixels of the file being played?

Thanks

Roey

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on MSDN and looks like the [WMP object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563945(v=VS.85).aspx) has some properties which might give you the [height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563861(v=VS.85).aspx) and [width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563862(v=VS.85).aspx).

You need to embed the control in a page and use JavaScript to access these properties.